# How to run one of multiple package.json scripts with PM2?

Tags: node.js, npm, server, pm2, package.json

I'm trying to run a script from my package.json with PM2. However, I am having trouble running the particular script. the scripts object in my package.json looks like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint src --ext .jsx",
    "clean": "rimraf ./www/build",
    "build": "npm run clean && NODE_ENV=production webpack",
    "server:prod": "NODE_ENV=production node server.js",
    "server:dev": "NODE_ENV=development node server.js"
},
```

With npm, I can use `npm run server:prod` to start my production server. However, PM2 doesn't take the run command. I've tried multiple combinations with `pm2 start` but none seem to work. Anyone know the right way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the npm scripts to use pm2 when starting the application.

```
"scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint src --ext .jsx",
    "clean": "rimraf ./www/build",
    "build": "npm run clean && NODE_ENV=production webpack",
    "server:prod": "NODE_ENV=production pm2 start server.js",
    "server:dev": "NODE_ENV=development pm2 start server.js"
},
```

Then you would still start your server with `npm run server:prod`.